# Importing and Testing variable from every .py file in directory

Tags: python, variables, import

Im trying to import and test the variable "builtin" from every python file in a directory. It should loop through every file and test the variable, and if the variable is set to true, then it will add the file name to a list. It should be able to also work if the file doesn't have the variable "builtin". Currently, my code is adding every file to the list, both files with and without the variable. How can i fix this? Here's my code:

```py
def getDefaults(folder):
    if folder == "plugins":
        files = os.listdir("plugins")
        defaults = []
        for file in files:
            try:
                exec("from plugins." + file[:-3] + " import builtin")
                if file[:-3].builtin == "True":
                    defaults.append(file)
            except:
                pass
        return defaults
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a global variable and have that variable assigned to builtin in exec statement.

```
import os

cur_builtin = None
def getDefaults(folder):
    if folder == "plugins":
        files = os.listdir("plugins")
        defaults = []
        for file in files:
            try:
                exec("global cur_builtin; from plugins." + file[:-3] + " import builtin; cur_builtin = builtin")
                if cur_builtin == "True":
                    defaults.append(file)
            except:
                pass
        return defaults


print (getDefaults("plugins"))
```

Test-

```
# code in filter_builtin.py
mkdir plugins
cd plugins
echo builtin = '"True"' >> sample1.py
echo builtin = '"True"' >> sample2.py
echo builtin = '"True"' >> sample3.py
echo builtin = '"False"' >> sample4.py
cd ..
python filter_builtin.py
```

Comment: It still includes all of the files that don't have the variable

Comment: did u try to print the getDefaults("plugins")? Do you still see all the filenames? I tested this code at my end before posting.

Comment: Nevermind, sorrry. There was an error with the code that was using getDefaults. Thanks